# Registering Barcode Scanner and receive data only from scanner using c#.net window forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want a library or code in c# that register raw Input and receive only from that device, i know the vendor id (vid) and product id(pid) of my barcode scanner. I tried a lot of libraries like sharpDx but no luck.

Comment: BarCode scanners usually return a string. You can configure your scanner (usually) to pass a prefix and/or a suffix along with the barcode, so you can determine which one sent it, using these values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i want to capture only from scanner in my app that is necessary for my logic.

Comment: Maybe you should give a better edscription of what that logic might be. Since you mentioned SharpDx, I might think that you want to capture the input of a Video source of sort. A Web Cam? Other video feed? Meaning, your app is meant to be the BarCode scanner. Is that so?

Comment: Or is it an industrial BarCode scanner, using a TCP/UDP connection? I don't know what you might have planned to use SharpDx for in this case, though.